# Github Pages Pushing Error

Tags: git, github

I'm using [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) to build my portfolio webpage. I've already built part of the website(it is online) and I get an error every time I try to update it.

The main HTML file for the webpage is named **index.html**. I am trying to add buttons to the website, so I added the buttons in my **index.html** file and saved it. Then I perform the following commands in my terminal (In the repository, of course):

```
git add index.html 
git commit -m "Adding buttons" 
git push origin master
```

Then I have to enter my username and password. I get the following error:

```
 To https://mywebsiteurl
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://mywebsiteurl'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How do I solve this error and push the changes to my repo?

Comment: Did you read the entire error message and do what it suggests?

Answer (score 0):

> **You need to do a pull.**

You or someone who has access to your repo pushed some changes which you don't have on your local version. Try following,

`git pull origin master`

It might be possible, you may find some **CONFLICTS**, just search for `<<<<` in file specified as conflicted. Read here more on [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: Actually, the only person who has access to my repo is me, but okay, I will pull and see what happens.

Comment: You might have pushed from some other machine.

Comment: I used the same machine.